# Uninitialized variable read error

Tags: c++, class, variables

Program to find the sum of digits of a number.

The compiled code gives an error:

```
runtime failure:variable 'z' is being used without being initialized.
```

If I initialize 'z' won't it erase the original value of z?

enter code here

```
#include<iostream>

#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
class sumd
{
int x;
  public:
void getdata()
{
    int z=0;
    cout<<"enter the no";
cin>>x;
z=x;
};
void sumdigit()
{
int z,y,sume,temp;             // this is the line with the error...
for(temp=z;temp>0;temp/=10)
{
    y=temp%10;
sume+=y;
}
cout<<sume;

};
};
  int main()
  {
  sumd s1;
   s1.getdata();
   s1.sumdigit();
   return 0;
      }
```

Comment: When you present code for SO, please avoid using tabs - it makes it hard to get a good layout.  Replace tabs by an appropriate number of blanks (there are tools to do that, on Unix at least), and then paste the result.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that in this method:

```
void sumdigit()
{
    int z,y,sume,temp;             // this is the line with the error...
    for(temp=z;temp>0;temp/=10)
    {
        y=temp%10;
        sume+=y;
    }
    cout<<sume;
}
```

You haven't given a value for `z` or `y`; they're uninitialized local variables.  I think that you probably intended to make `z` and `y` data members of the enclosing class.  Try moving the definition of those variables outside of this method and see if that fixes things.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `y` isn't being used uninitialised, and doesn't look like it should be a member; it's just declared at a wider scope than it strictly needs to be. It looks like you're right about `z` though; and `sume` needs initialising to zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'original' value for z at this point.
I assume you are thinking that the value of z in the getdata function will be saved?
Well it won't. You have to return the value of z from the function and pass it to the sumdigit function

Comment: i'm a newbie can you explain it a lil bit more

Comment: Ah I didn't notice you are using classes. Go with templatetypedef's answer and you should be fine.